# How to reflect updates on table, when database is updated using GET in AJAX, Jquery

Tags: javascript, php, jquery, mysql, ajax

I have a table in my php file that is displayed using datatables.
Upon clicking on a link in a row of the table, the database is updated using Jquery and GET AJAX.
My database is getting updated, but table does not reflect the changes without a manual refresh.
How do I make it possible, for the table values to reflect the changes immediately after the button is clicked.
Code below:

```
$("#note").click(function(){
                var note = prompt('Enter note');

                if(note){ 

                    var xmlhttp = new XMLHttpRequest();
                    xmlhttp.onreadystatechange = function() {
                        if (xmlhttp.readyState == 4 && xmlhttp.status == 200) 
                        {
                            alert("Record updated");
                        }
                    };
                    xmlhttp.open("GET", "db_update.php?id="+id+"&note="+note, true);
                    xmlhttp.send();


                    /* $.get("db_update.php", { id: id[$index], note:note });  */
                }
                return false;

            });
```

Please advise.

Comment: can u check this https://datatables.net/reference/api/ajax.reload()

Answer (score 0):

If you are using jquery datatable than this will help you:

```
$('#table_id').DataTable().ajax.reload();
```

otherwise make an ajax call to get the updated data from the database

Comment: This is not working.
Im getting this warning:
DataTables warning: table id=leads - Invalid JSON response. For more information about this error, please see http://datatables.net/tn/1

Comment: I am using the same in my project at more than 10 places and it is working fine.

Comment: What is your query like. I am updating the database, which is working fine, but the values are not getting reflected in datatables and I keep getting this warning.

Answer (score 0):

You can do something like this

```
var id= "your id here";
var note = "Your default note";

var table = $('#dataTable').DataTable( {
        ajax: "db_update.php?id="+id+"&note="+note
});

$("#note").click(function(){
   var note = prompt('Enter note');
   table.ajax.url( "db_update.php?id="+id+"&note="+note ).load();     
});
```

Comment: The id variable is the id of the row that has the link I clicked on and the note is entered in prompt on clicking the link.
How can i access these variables while calling datatable()